# Loading symbol for app.exe in c# winform

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

When I run my Winform, I get no exception or error, and I don't see my form, but at the bottom of Visual Studio I see this:

[image]

and it's not showing anything else.

My program.cs code

```
 static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
```

How I can resolve this?

Comment: Disable the installed anti-malware product and try again.  If its is Avast then get rid of it as soon as possible.

Answer (score -1):

If this is a git project, try

```
git clean -dfx
```

Do this with Visual Studio closed.

[git clean documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean)